# Removing .php part in URL on a multisite Codeigniter install

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter-based system with two apps in it, *app* and *site*, which share a single *system* folder. The former has the backend, latter has the front-end. Because of this, index.php defaults to *site* and there is a separate `app.php` to access the backend.

`http://localhost/subdirectory/` goes to the frontend, while to access the backend I have to write `http://localhost/subdirectory/app.php`.

I have referred to the User Guide on how to remove the *index.php* thing, and it works on the frontend. Say, `http://localhost/subdirectory/pages/about` successfully goes to the *site* folder's *pages* class with an argument of *about*.

The issue is when I try to access the login page, the URI points to `http://localhost/subdirectory/app.php/auth/login`. Entering `http://localhost/subdirectory/app/auth/login` returns the 403 Forbidden page, which <del>I presume to be the *index.html* on the folder</del> **UPDATE:** discovered that it's due to the .htaccess present on *app*.

How can I remove the *app.php* part?

Here's my application structure:

```
app
| - cache, config, controllers, views, and other related CI folders
site
| - cache, config, etc, like app
system
| - CI's system folder
app.php
index.php
.htaccess
```

And here's my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(app)/(.*)$ app.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

That doesn't work.

Any help? Thank you!

**UPDATE**: 403 Forbidden the shows up is caused by .htaccess with a content of "Deny from All", not only because of *index.html*. I don't know if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out through restructuring my architecture.

Here it is:

```
app
| - (application name for backend) folder
| -- models, config, controllers, etc. folders
| - index.php for backend
site
| - models, config, controllers, etc.
system
| - CI system folder
index.php for the frontend (which is on 'site')
```

Turns out it looks like we don't need messy arm-wrestling with .htaccess for this to work. This just made myself look really dumb.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `.htaccess` carefully:

```
RewriteRule ^(app)/(.*)$ app.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

In this Rule, `$1` will points to `"app"` string, not the section comes after forward slash.

Change that line as below, and let me know what happens please:

```
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ app.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

**UPDATE:**
Here's a sample of `.htaccess` file, according to [CI Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html), I didn't try this, please let me know how it works:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|app\.php|public|app)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond $1 ^app/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: in `.htaccess` file, comment `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` phrase out and try again, I suggest you using CI [recommended rules](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) to rewrite urls.

Comment: Doesn't work too. May I ask how would the new .htaccess would look like for this scenario based on CI's original rules?

Comment: Still throws the 403. In addition, using `http://localhost/subdirectory/app.php` introduces a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was doing a website with an admin panel and a front end area. Try using the standard removing the index.php method and use the routes function of codeigniter instead.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Goodluck!

Comment: That was the first thing I did. The problem is the planned architecture of the system requires the two areas to be entirely separate so as not to interfere with an area if there are changes with the other. So I really need it to be separate.

Answer (score 0):

you can route to app | site in other way

```
//index.php
if(preg_match('/^app/ui', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
     require_onse "app.php";
} else {
     require_onse "site.php"
}
```